# Does Firebase has direct cloud function trigger?

Tags: firebase

In times when Parse.com was on they had a function that called a cloud function directly and returned whatever I wanted. So I could have all the server logic on the server, not in client code. Doe's Firebase has it as well? I can't find it - all I found are HTTP triggers, but it implies that it's not available through Javascript SDK. Am I missing something or do I have to use REST interface for that?

Answer (score 0):

To run server-side code that is triggered by events in Firebase, you'd use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). Currently these can trigger code through the Firebase Database updates, Authentication, Analytics, Cloud Storage **and** HTTP. The documentation I linked has all the details.

Comment: So HTTP is the only way to call function without triggers? No SDK wrappers to just point the function and get the data? Also, does HTTP authenticate so I can make it safe for fragile data?

Answer (score 0):

As Frank van Puffelen has explained you could use [Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), I'll like to add a couple of things.

- You could also use the [Firebase Database Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) for the Database, this requires you have a server
- Firebase Functions is a sort of *big brother*, constantly listening for whatever you want. Currently starting and deploying functions is fairly easy and fast, I love this [how to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EvV9Vk9iOCQ). Basically, you have to install the CLI and then using commands, create a project, write your js for Functions and for deploying those changes to Firebase Functions use the CLI again
- Functions can listen more than what the Admin SDK can, the Admin SDK is for the Database while Functions is for, authentification, database, and cloud messaging. This means any user registration or deletion or any change in a node, can trigger further logic. This logic could include sending push notifications. There is a [github](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) repo where you can see a lot of examples, I made myself a [small repo](https://github.com/cutiko/testing-functions) for the same purpose